# Calculating I/O wait time in java program

Tags: java, io, jmx

I want to measure I/O wait time for the CPU where my application will be running.

I couldn't find anything for fetching I/O wait time in JMX. But what i found is I can get `CPUTime` and `UserTime` and calculate `SystemTime`. `SystemTime` will give me an idea of time spent running OS code on behalf of my application(which will include I/O too).

Is there any other way to fetch I/O wait time from java application?

Question is not about which tool to use for that. I want to capture it send it to logs.

Comment: Just curious.. *Why do you want to do that?*. Especially when you have millions of lines of code embedded in your OS to improve performance when using IO operations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568974/how-to-measure-i-o-time-for-a-java-application-running-on-ubuntu

Comment: You can't "calculate" it, but you can *measure* it.

Comment: ok "measure", but is there a way to do it in java program

Comment: @TheLostMind I have to capture CPU metrics and send it to logs and hence the question